# how to generate token from azure AD app client id?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have `one application which is register into azure AD.`
I have `client id with me and secret key is inside the key vault.`

> How to access that secure Azure AD register api using console app ?

I guess i `need a bearer token for it how to generate it?`

I search on and I got something like below code -

```
var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-aad-tenant-id/oauth2/token";
var context = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var resource = "https://some-resource-you-want-access-to";

var clientCredentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredentials);
```

Comment: Is this console app just for testing purposes? or is it a real client that will continue to use this API in a production scenario? I ask this because if it's a real client, you should register it as a separate application in Azure AD and NOT try to use the clientID and secret of the API itself.. I can give you more specific guidance in an answer depending on what case it is..

Comment: this is real client application production scenario. what needs to be done in that case ? it will be great help if you point out something here

Comment: Is the console app running on a client machine? You realize the client secret will be effectively public then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the code below to generate the token, in my sample, I generate the token for `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

```
string graphResourceId = "https://graph.microsoft.com/";
string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-aad-tenant-id/oauth2/token";
string tenantId = "your-aad-tenant-id";
string clientId = "your-clientid";
string secret = "your-secret";
authority = String.Format(authority, tenantId);
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
var accessToken = authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, new ClientCredential(clientId, secret)).Result.AccessToken;
```

[image]

Comment: bu ti do not have secret key ? i think they have added that into key vault how to use it from key vault if so ?

Comment: @Neo You could refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52584954/fetching-secrets-from-keyvault-from-azure-in-c-sharp/52585259#52585259) for their ways.